# Android SimpleDateFormt get wrong month name

Tags: android, date, localization, format

I want to convert the months of integers, to names. But in some languages the month names are wrong, for example, in Italian and English are exact, while in Russian and Polish are wrong. This is what I do with SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
              SimpleDateFormat postFormater  = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");

                String eDDte;
                try {
                    Date nDate = curFormater.parse(d.mese);//d.mese = 01
                    eDDte = postFormater.format(nDate);
                    tvMonth.setText(eDDte.toUpperCase());                     
                }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                }
```

Comment: How about `SimpleDatFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLL");`?